# PSCustomObject incorrectly formatting output

Tags: powershell

I am having issues adding in data to a PSCustomObject.

My script uses Invoke-RestMethod to request data from an API, from which I then store in a variable and use Select-Object and Format-Table to output it nicely. The initial issue I ran into was that the date and time returned in the response was in ISO8601 format which just isn't nice to look at. So, using the below code I have formatted the date and time into a much more readable format and stored it in its own PSCustomObject, however I run into an issue when returning that formatted datetime back to the original PSCustomObject.

Prior to using Add-Member to add the data into the PSCustomObject variable the data displays great, however as soon as it is added back in, and I try to run a command such as Select-Object or Format-Table a bunch of padding is added which completely messes up my output yet when directly accessing the value it displays as expected. I am absolutely stuck here on how to resolve this. (The below code starts just after I use Invoke-RESTMethod and store the returned data to variable).

```
## Extracts the time property from the PSCustomObject and re-formats it to an easily readable format.
$datetime = $HTTPResponse.psobject.Properties.value | Select-Object -Property time
$uDateTimeRegex = $datetime -replace "[@]" -replace "[}]" -replace "[=]" -replace "[{]" -replace "time" -replace "[Z]" -split ' '

ForEach ($SplitTime in $uDateTimeRegex){
    $FormattedDateTimeArray = ($uDateTimeRegex).split('.') | Select-String -Pattern '[a-z]'
}

$CorrectDateTime = @()
$CorrectDateTime = for ($i=0; $i -lt $FormattedDateTimeArray.count; $i++) {
    [datetime]::ParseExact($FormattedDateTimeArray[$i], 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss', $null).ToString('HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy')
}

## Converts the newly created $CorrectDateTime array into a PSCustomObject
$CaseTimeObj = ForEach ($dt in $CorrectDateTime){

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        CaseDateTime = $dt
    }
}
## Uses a foreach loop and Add-Member to add the contents of PSCustomObject $CaseTimeObj to the pre-existing PSCustomObject created from the HTTP reponse
$objProperties = Get-Member -InputObject $CaseTimeObj -MemberType Property
foreach ($p in $objProperties){
    $HTTPResponse | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CaseDateTime -Value $CaseTimeObj.$($p.Name) -Force
}

## Selects required values from PSCustomObject variable and formats them for output
$HTTPOutput = $HTTPResponse.psobject.Properties.value | Select-Object -Property Title, userAssigned, id, CaseDateTime, environment | Format-Table @{L='Case Name';E={$_.Title}}, @{L='Assigned User';E={$_.userAssigned}}, @{L='Case ID';E={$_.id}}, @{L='Creation Time';E={$_.CaseDateTime}}, @{L='Client';E={$_.environment}} 

$HTTPOutput
```

[Output using above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Sos.png)

[Output with default HTTP response, no modifying datetime stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjGQo.png)

[Directly accessing the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgJdE.png)

[Accessing the values using Select-Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXV3w.png)

EDIT, Contents of the $datetime variable as requested:

```
PS > $datetime

time
----
2020-04-23T16:26:44.626Z
2020-04-23T16:27:47.511Z
2020-04-23T16:28:29.394Z
2020-04-23T16:28:58.413Z
2020-04-23T16:29:24.936Z
2020-04-23T16:29:59.462Z
2020-04-23T16:30:31.927Z
2020-04-23T16:31:07.173Z
2020-04-23T16:40:23.39Z
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the http response body from invoke-restmethod, your expected output, and the output you’re currently getting as text rather than images?

Comment: @mclayton - I can't unfortunately, what is it about the images that isn't clear and I can try clarify for you?

Comment: to enable testing your code, please post a sample of the 1st 3 or 4 lines of the `$datetime` collection.DO NOT post it as an image, and DO put in in your Question wrapped in code formatting. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey added that output.

Comment: @takeoff127 - our code shows a regex replace targeting many characters that are not in the sample data you show. is that actually the content of `$uDateTimeRegex`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so those characters are actually there, but because $datetime is a PSCustomObject they aren't displayed in output. In the line below, where $uDateTimeRegex is declared, the PSCustomObject is converted to a string, therefore those characters need to be removed.

Comment: @takeoff127 - no ... there are NO such chars in a datetime object. none. nada. zero. zilch. [*grin*] that is the whole reason one keeps things in datetime _objects_ instead of datetime _strings_. the chars you seem to be removing look like one of the ISO formats ... but that is NOT stored in any datetime _object_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that isn't a datetime object though, its a PSCustomObject saved into a variable called $datetime.

Comment: @takeoff127 - we are cross communicating to no useful effect. i will just drop this since i can't make myself understood. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey regardless, I appreciate you trying to help, thanks!

Comment: @takeoff127 - you are quite welcome! glad to kinda-sorta-almost help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you are really over-complicating this.

The dates in the $HTTPResponse are in ISO8601 format, so real easy to convert to a datetime **object**.

You can do that with either `Get-Date '2020-04-23T16:26:44.626Z'` or with `[datetime]::Parse('2020-04-23T16:26:44.626Z')`.

Both methods will result in a datetime object, converted to **local time**.
If you need the date to **remain UTC**, do `(Get-Date '2020-04-23T16:26:44.626Z').ToUniversalTime()` or `([datetime]::Parse('2020-04-23T16:26:44.626Z')).ToUniversalTime()`

Creating a datetime object allows you to format it in any way you like, even the (IMO quite bizarre) `'HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy'` string format.

All this can be done in a calculated property:

```
$HTTPOutput = $HTTPResponse.psobject.Properties.value | 
              Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Case Name'; Expression = {$_.Title}}, 
                                      @{Name = 'Assigned User'; Expression = {$_.userAssigned}}, 
                                      @{Name = 'Case ID'; Expression = {$_.id}}, 
                                      @{Name = 'Creation Time'; Expression = { '{0:HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy}' -f [datetime]::Parse($_.time)}}, 
                                      @{Name = 'Client'; Expression = {$_.environment}}

# output on screen
$HTTPOutput | Format-Table -AutoSize

# if you like, output to CSV file
$HTTPOutput | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\TheOutput.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you don't care about creating the $HTTPOutput object array and simply just want to display on screen, then you can use the same calculated properties directly on `Format-Table`.

This will not return anything else but data on screen in a table format:

```
$HTTPResponse.psobject.Properties.value |
Format-Table @{Name = 'Case Name'; Expression = {$_.Title}}, 
             @{Name = 'Assigned User'; Expression = {$_.userAssigned}}, 
             @{Name = 'Case ID'; Expression = {$_.id}}, 
             @{Name = 'Creation Time'; Expression = { '{0:HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy}' -f [datetime]::Parse($_.time)}}, 
             @{Name = 'Client'; Expression = {$_.environment}}
```

Comment: Yeah so that code does exactly what I wanted... I guess my issue stems from not properly understanding the datetime object, in fact I don't fully understand the code you have posted but I will go away and do further learning. Many thanks for your time. (p.s why is my desired time format bizzare? :D)

Comment: @takeoff127 Thanks. Bizarre to me, because I have never seen the hour and minute part **before** the actual datepart in any context before. Usually, it is something like 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'. Anyway, if that is what you need in the output, go for it.

Comment: in this instance, the date isn't as important as there *shouldn't* be any cases from any other date but the current, that's why I have the time set to be displayed first. Thanks once again, it's no exaggeration to say I was working on trying to solve this for 5+ hours before posting here.